# AWS CodeBuild: "Failed to login to GitHub, please reconnect your account"

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud

I had CodeBuild authorised with my GitHub through the AWS Console, but then I revoked the GitHub OAuth (in preparation for attaching a CI GitHub user). Now it insists "Failed to login to GitHub, please reconnect your account", but I honestly cannot find where to do so -- thoughts?

[screenshot of error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qUft8.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the CodeBuild console/UI, you will find an option to "disconnect from GitHub" when creating a CodeBuild project or editing the source provider of an existing project. Once you have disconnected on the UI, you would also want to sign off of GitHub if you have an authenticated browser session with you non-CI GitHub login. Then simply click on connect to GitHub when creating or editing the CodeBuild project. You will need to sign-in as the GitHub user that you want CodeBuild to access repositories from.

Note CodeBuild only supports one GitHub login/OAuth per AWS account Id. So all projects in your AWS account share the same GitHub repo access. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But it is important to note that this option is not accessible if you have the new look UI enabled -- the error message replaces the entire UI. On the dashboard for developer tools there was an option to go back to the old UI, and from there I was able to click the "disconnect from GitHub" option under source providers

Comment: This should be addressed now. Thanks for reporting this issue.